# float left two divs and second div position fixed - float doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I've this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/2z2ksLy4/

HTML:

```
<div class="one">
test
</div>
<div class="two">
test2
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.one{
  width:400px;
  border:1px solid red;
  min-height: 200px;
  float:left;
  display:block;
}
.two{
  width:200px;
  border:1px solid red;
  heigth: 200px;
  float:left;
  display:block; 
  position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
test
</div>
<div class="two">
test2
</div>
```

Why doesn't work the float in the second div (div with class .two)?

The second div behaves like a `position:abosolute`.

Maybe somebody can explain me this behavior.

Comment: What is actual requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you apply `position:fixed` on any element it is not relative to any other div any more. After `position:fixed` it is relative to body only.

So you can align it with css properties `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right` but you can't align it after the previous div just with float left.

Read these for refrence : http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp, https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Comment: Ok thank you. That is new for me... Than I've to get the width of the first div with javascript and can replace the left of the second div. I think that is the perfect answer? Because my first div has a dynamic width.